# Обработка пустых переменных

Tags: php

Имеется переменная содержащая текст из переменных $g1 $g2 $g3 $g4. Каждая из них пишется на отдельной строке:

```
$two =  "$g1\r\n$g2\r\n$g3\r\n$g4";
```

Проблема в том, что некоторые переменные из ($g1 $g2 $g3 $g4) могут оказаться пустыми, а на их месте остается пустая строка. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Gs = array( $g1, $g2, $g3, $g4); // все переменные в массив
foreach( $Gs AS $key=>$value) if( empty( $value)) unset( $Gs[ $key]); // удаляем пустышки из массива
$two = implode( "\r\n", $Gs); // склеиваем элементы массива символами новой строки
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$two = '';
$two .= (empty($g1))? '' : $g1.'\n';
$two .= (empty($g2))? '' : $g2.'\n';
...
```

Можно в цикл завернуть

```
  $two = '';
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $t = "g$i"
    $two .= (empty($$t))? '' : $$t.'\n';
  }
```

или функцию

```
function voc($var) {
    return (empty($var))? '' : $var.'\n';
}
$two = voc($g1) . voc($g2) . voc($g3) . voc($g4);
```

Добавлено: По синтаксису для новичков: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%E5%F0%ED%E0%F0%ED%E0%FF_%F3%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E0%FF_%EE%EF%E5%F0%E0%F6%E8%FF

http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: лучше тогда уж замену сделать, чем такое городить. ну или в конце концов объявить функцию....

Comment: Можно ещё и в цикле переменные перебирать по именам переменных, и класс объявить, и регекспами... А на кой, если оно больше нигде в коде не используется, а спрашивает явный новичёк? 
Не зная контекста использования -- предпочитаю простые решения.

Comment: @mayar, **DRY** новичкам как раз очень вредно давать эти простыни, потом встречаешь их в реальной жизни.

Comment: @eicto Вы правы. Дополнил ответ. Проверьте, пожалуйста, а то давно я на ПХП не писал...

Answer (score 0):

Можно объявить функцию, которая склеит аргументы и пропустит пустой

```
function skipJoin($glue='',$firstarg='') {
    $args=func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value)) unset($args[$key]);
    }
    return join($glue,$args);
}

echo skipJoin("\n",'b','a','e','','f');
```

но вообще мне кажется, что простой preg_replace() вполне будет нормальным решением.